# How to validate Google Oauth2.0 access token from client in spring boot so that resource are accessible to a valid Access Token user only

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

I know how to apply spring boot security even though I'm new to it.I also understand how to use spring boot to create oauthlogin so that only users who have been verified by Google can access our API .However, if we have a client application (front end) with a Google sign-in option, the client will receive an access code and a refresh token upon successful login on front end side .How can I validate this client access token in Spring Boot, ensuring that only clients with legitimate access tokens can access all resources?